# Why first variation of function works but second doesn't?

Tags: javascript

Function 1. Works perfectly. Makes a div flicker.

```
function makeItFlicker(){
        let y = document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor;
        if (y=="blue"){
            document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = "#557a95";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    }
    setInterval(makeItFlicker, 500);
```

This doesn't. I just changed number to it's hashtag value.

```
function makeItFlicker(){
        let y = document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor;
        if (y=="#90acc0"){
            document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = "#557a95";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = "#90acc0";
        }
    }
    setInterval(makeItFlicker, 500);
```

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Well the string `"blue"` is not the same as the string `"#90acc0"` ... JavaScript has no idea that you're comparing colors. In general you can't rely on browsers to report color values in any particular format.

Comment: What do you mean? It's just a string anyway, something should be preventing it from working.

Comment: because browsers will convert the text to the color it represents, so when the function is called again, y is set to "rgb(85, 122, 149)"

Comment: You'd be better off controlling the color with a CSS rule and toggling a class on and off.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers handle colors differently. Sometimes it's HEX, sometimes it's RGBA, RGB, will this change in the future browser updates? who knows and who cares. You can store the interpreted color into a `data-*` attribute...

But hey, why don't we try first a **pure CSS** solution using **animation keyframes**

```css
#x {
  padding: 50px;
  background: blue;
  animation: blink 0.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {background: #557a95;}
}
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```

If you really want JS... than you could store the current background inside a `data-*` attribute, and than simply toggle back and forth the data and background color values:

```js
const blinkBackground = el => {
  const blink = el.getAttribute('data-blink');        // get current data...
  el.setAttribute('data-blink', el.style.background); // (store current bg value)
  el.style.background = blink;                        // ...and set it as background
}


document.querySelectorAll('[data-blink]').forEach(el =>
   setInterval(blinkBackground.bind(null, el), 500)
);
```

```css
[data-blink] {padding: 10px; margin: 10px; background: blue;}
```

```html
<div data-blink="#557a95"></div>
<div data-blink="red"></div>
<div data-blink="hsla(100, 50%, 80%, 0.8)"></div>
```

You can also store an array of colors:

```js
const blinkBackground = el => {
  const c = JSON.parse(el.getAttribute('data-blink'));
  el.style.background = c[0];
  el.setAttribute('data-blink', JSON.stringify(c.reverse()));
}

document.querySelectorAll('[data-blink]').forEach(el =>
   setInterval(blinkBackground.bind(null, el), 500)
);
```

```css
[data-blink] {padding: 10px; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<div data-blink='["#557a95", "blue"]'></div>
<div data-blink='["rgb(0,0,0)", "gold"]'></div>
<div data-blink='["orange", "hsla(100, 50%, 80%, 0.8)"]'></div>
```

Comment: this is a beautiful solution but not really the answer to that question

Answer (score 1):

because `style.backgroundColor` returns the rgb value not the string value of the color.

so in the second function y will have a value like this `rgb(255, 241, 35)`

you can use this method to convert the results to the hex string value

```
function rgbToHex(str) {
    let values = str.replace('rgb(', '').replace(')', '').split(',');
    let r = values[0], g = values[1], b = values[2];
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

> "Different browsers behave differently with color values" @Pointy

I've tested that on both chrome and safari, and it returns the same value, bus sure we need to make sure its working cross browsers

Comment: Different browsers behave differently with color values.

Comment: @Pointy this is true but it is the correct answer at this point. He could explain it better maybe, but for sure this is the problem of the Topic Poster

Comment: I've tested that on both chrome and safari, and it returns the same value, bus sure we need to make sure its working cross browsers, thanks :)

Comment: @messerbill sure, agreed